# Gemstones in a Treasure Hoard

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am using the [Appendix](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/appendix.html) in Ultimate Equipment to generate a Treasure Hoard.

A 1000 GP (Type H Treasure, Lair Treasure) contains "three grade 1 gemstones", but the gemstone tables aren't referenced like that they're by "Least Semi-Precious Gem" or "Greater Semi-Precious Gem" etc..

How does the grading on the treasure tables relate to the random gem tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the table **Type B Treasure, Coins and Gems**, you can see that gemstones are given in 6 grades, ranking from 1 (least valuable) to 6 (most valuable).

As you have pointed out, the table **Random Gems** has more distinct description. There are 6 categories ranging from *least semi-precious gem* to *greater precious gem*, with increasing gem value.

Because of the mentioned similarities, a direct association between the 6 grades and the 6 categories is the (only) logical choice.